# Create JSON having a specific structure in Python by merging dictionaries in a blank master dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So, I have JSON data that I am getting from an HTML form. I have to format this data to have a specific JSON structure as shown below.

```
[
 {
   "Header": "Stats",
   "Line_01": "Line 01",
   "Line_02": "Line 02",
   "Line_03": "Line 03",
   "Line_04": "Line 04",
   "Line_05": "Line 05",
   "Line_06": "Line 06",
   "Line_07": "Line 07"
 },
 {
   "Header": "JUV",
   "Line_01": "89",
   "Line_02": "34",
   "Line_03": "765",
   "Line_04": "123",
   "Line_05": "1",
   "Line_06": "4",
   "Line_07": "455"
 },
 {
   "Header": "SMP",
   "Line_01": "12",
   "Line_02": "89",
   "Line_03": "124",
   "Line_04": "678",
   "Line_05": "92",
   "Line_06": "120",
   "Line_07": "5"
 }
]
```

JSON I have from the HTML form is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "00",
        "value": "JUV"
    },
    {
        "name": "00",
        "value": "STATS"
    },
    {
        "name": "00",
        "value": "SMP"
    },
    {
        "name": "00",
        "value": "89"
    },
    {
        "name": "01",
        "value": "LINE 01"
    },
    {
        "name": "02",
        "value": "12"
    },
    {
        "name": "03",
        "value": "34"
    },
    {
        "name": "04",
        "value": "LINE 02"
    },
    {
        "name": "05",
        "value": "89"
    },
    {
        "name": "06",
        "value": "765"
    },
    {
        "name": "07",
        "value": "LINE 03"
    },
    {
        "name": "08",
        "value": "124"
    },
    {
        "name": "09",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "name": "10",
        "value": "LINE 04"
    },
    {
        "name": "11",
        "value": "678"
    },
    {
        "name": "12",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "13",
        "value": "LINE 05"
    },
    {
        "name": "14",
        "value": "92"
    },
    {
        "name": "15",
        "value": "4"
    },
    {
        "name": "16",
        "value": "LINE 06"
    },
    {
        "name": "17",
        "value": "120"
    },
    {
        "name": "18",
        "value": "455"
    },
    {
        "name": "19",
        "value": "LINE 07"
    },
    {
        "name": "20",
        "value": "5"
    }
]
```

The form looks like this: HTML form - Image on Pasteboard

The Python code I am trying so far is:

```
import json

jarr = []
final_file = {}
json_template = {
   "Header": "",
   "Line_01": "",
   "Line_02": "",
   "Line_03": "",
   "Line_04": "",
   "Line_05": "",
   "Line_06": "",
   "Line_07": ""
 }

with open("testo101.json",) as f:
    jdata = json.load(f)

k = 0

for i in range(8):         
    a =[]
    for j in range(3):     
         a.append(jdata[k]['value'])
         k+=1
    jarr.append(a)

for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][1]
final_file.update(json_template)
for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][0]
final_file.update(json_template)
for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][2]     
final_file.update(json_template)

print(final_file)
```

So what I have done so far is:

- Import the JSON file I got from HTML form.
- Covert it into a 3x8 matrix... so I can get values of each column
  easily.
- I can fill values from the JSON in the `json_template` dictionary with
  the help of 2D array I just created.

**The Problem:**

I can't figure out how to merge the 3 dictionaries that I am generating from each column of the 2D array into a single dictionary `final_file` so I can dump it as a JSON file and that's what I want. How can I do this... or if there is some other better way to do this then please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These code should do the job:

```
import json

jarr = []
final_file = [] # CHANGE #1
json_template = {
   "Header": "",
   "Line_01": "",
   "Line_02": "",
   "Line_03": "",
   "Line_04": "",
   "Line_05": "",
   "Line_06": "",
   "Line_07": ""
 }

with open("testo101.json",) as f:
    jdata = json.load(f)

k = 0

for i in range(8):         
    a =[]
    for j in range(3):     
         a.append(jdata[k]['value'])
         k+=1
    jarr.append(a)

for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][1]
final_file.append(json_template.copy()) # CHANGE #2
for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][0]
final_file.append(json_template.copy()) # CHANGE #2
for i, x in enumerate(json_template):
    json_template[x]=jarr[i][2]     
final_file.append(json_template.copy()) # CHANGE #2


with open('yourjson.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(final_file, jsonfile, indent=4)
```

I made two changes to your code:

1. You need a list of dictionaries, not just one dictionary to dump three dictionaries, so I changed final_file to a list.
2. After you make each json_template, I attached **a copy of the template** to the list. (`.copy()` is important, otherwise later changes will be reflected in the previous entries and you end up getting three of the same item).

I wrote the dumping code and attached it to the end. You can open `yourjson.json` to see the result.